# How to highlight a specific file in hidden folder?

Tags: powershell

This basic script creates directory and .txt file in it. This file contains some data made in script. I try to open folder and highlight a specific txt file in the end of process.

IMO the problem is about hidden folder (C:\Users\Public\Desktop). 
How should i change it, so it will work? I still want this folder to be hidden.

When i use different path (no hidden folder in it, for example C:\Users) it highlights without any problem.

```
$username = "test1"
$password = "test2"
$path = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\test\$username.txt"


Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ -Force
New-Item C:\Users\Public\Desktop\test\$username.txt -Force
Set-Content C:\Users\Public\Desktop\test\$username.txt "Username: $username

Password: $password"

explorer /select,$path -Force
```

Comment: What happens exactly? The Explorer window appears? In the correct folder? Is the _wrong_ item highlighted, or is _nothing_ highlighted?

Comment: It opens default Explorer window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Force` is not a valid argument for [explorer](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html).

Remove it:

```
explorer /select,$path
```